# Converting or rotating the csv into a specific format in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
    ,,22-5-2021 (v_c) , 23-5-2021 (v_c)
    col_a,col_b,v_c,v_d,v_c,v_d
    1,1,2,4,5,6
    2,2,2,3,7,6
    3,3,2,5,6,5
```

I need to convert it to:

```
col_a,col_b,v_c,v_d,dates
1,1,2,4,22-5-2021
1,1,5,6,23-5-2021
2,2,2,3,22-5-2021
2,2,7,6,23-5-2021
3,3,2,5,22-5-2021
3,3,6,5,23-5-2021
```

or

```
col_a,col_b,v_c,v_d,dates
1,1,2,4,22-5-2021
2,2,2,3,22-5-2021
3,3,2,5,22-5-2021
1,1,5,6,23-5-2021
2,2,7,6,23-5-2021
3,3,6,5,23-5-2021
```

My approach was using df.melt, but didn't quite get it. Maybe I'm lost with how to bring dates that are for 2 columns each.

Comment: sir did your query solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can try via list comprehension+`pd.wide_to_long()`:

```
df=pd.read_csv('etc.csv',header=1)
df.columns=[x if x.split('.')[-1].isnumeric() else x+'.0' for x in df]
df=(pd.wide_to_long(df,['v_c','v_d'],['col_a.0','col_b.0'],'drop',sep='.')
      .reset_index().sort_values('drop'))
df['dates']=df.pop('drop').map({0:'22-5-2021',1:'23-5-2021'})
df.columns=df.columns.str.rstrip('.0')
```

output of `df`:

```
    col_a   col_b   v_c v_d dates
0   1       1       2   4   22-5-2021
2   2       2       2   3   22-5-2021
4   3       3       2   5   22-5-2021
1   1       1       5   6   23-5-2021
3   2       2       7   6   23-5-2021
5   3       3       6   5   23-5-2021
```

Comment: Why did we alter the column names on line 2? Is there a way to also get the dates?

Comment: @LearnerJS because of `wide_to_long()` we we don't do this it will throw error.......also if you have few dates then mapping is easy....updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**